# how to refer the url to the perticular block of the body in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Is it possible to redirect to the particular part of the  page.

I created the `div` with id="refrence" like `<div id="reference">` in the page

Now how can I refer this div from URL in Word Press. I tried to create the url

myblog/page1#reference during creating of the page but no success..

any help would be appriciable.

Comment: @Rikesh -- iin wp i cant give #reference at the end of the url  it is my problem

Answer (score 1):

you should use HTML anchor for that, not DIV:

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

or

```
<a name="TOC">Table of Contents</a>
```

and link there like that:

```
<a href="#TOC">Table of Contents</a>
```